# store how to large decimal numbers in mysql

Tags: mysql

i have a column in my table currently set as `decimal(10,2)`

but i want to be able to store `0.001299999999` which would round to `0.0013`

how should this be stored in my MySQL table?

Comment: I think `0.001299999999` would be _truncated_ to zero.

Comment: what should my field be set as?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html ... increase the number of decimal places, if you really need that level of precision

Comment: so should 10,2 not do this?

Comment: First number is how many places total, second is how many go *after* the decimal. Is 2 enough to hold 001299999999? You tell me. If you want 4, ask for 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECIMAL (10,8)
```

> The declaration syntax for a DECIMAL column is DECIMAL(M,D). The ranges of values for the arguments in MySQL 5.7 are as follows:
>
> M is the maximum number of digits (the precision). It has a range of 1 to 65.
>
> D is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point (the scale). It has a range of 0 to 30 and must be no larger than M.

**[Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html)**